# How do I pass a list to a controller from an Html.RadioButtonFor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So basically I Have a view that has a Create New button and then a list of items, on the list of items I want to have a radiobutton that will allow the user to select it and carry over the details of the item to the Create New page when they Click on Create New

This is what I have on my view currently:

```
 <tbody>
       @for (int i = 0; i < Model.newExpenseFOPList.Count; i++)
         {   
        <tr>         
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newExpenseFOPList[@i].Category, new {style="width:100px; border-style: none;", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus="this.blur()", @maxlength = "60"})</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newExpenseFOPList[@i].SubCategory, new {style="width:150px; border-style: none;", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus="this.blur()", @maxlength = "60"})</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newExpenseFOPList[@i].CreditFund, new {style="width:45px; border-style: none;", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus="this.blur()",  @maxlength = "8"})
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newExpenseFOPList[@i].CreditORGN, new {style="width:45px; border-style: none;", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus="this.blur()",  @maxlength = "8"})
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newExpenseFOPList[@i].CreditProgram, new {style="width:45px; border-style: none;", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus="this.blur()",  @maxlength = "5"})</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newExpenseFOPList[@i].Amount, new { style="width:70px; border-style: none;",  @maxlength = "50", @onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"})</td>
          <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.newExpenseFOPList[@i].CopyRadioButton, "CopyRadioButton",  new { @Name="group1", @Value="copy"}) </td>
        </tr>
         }                       
 </tbody>
```

And this is the controller tied to this view:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Expense(NewExpenseViewModel newExpenseViewModel, string submitAction, EditExpenseViewModel editExpenseViewModel)
        {
            //declare a variable of type list of ExpenseDistModel and fetch the SP getExpenseList values into it
            List<ExpenseDistModel> expenseModelList = DataAccess.getExpenseList();

            //instantiate the viewModel along with the values previously fetched by expenseModel
            editExpenseViewModel = new EditExpenseViewModel(expenseModelList);



            //Check Category is not already in the table or that the field is not empty 
            for (int i = 0; i < newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseFOPList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (newExpenseViewModel.selectedExpenseCategory == newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseFOPList[i].Category && newExpenseViewModel.selectedExpenseSubCategory == newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseFOPList[i].SubCategory || newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseFOPList[i].Category == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message1 = "Category already exists or the field is empty.";

                    //invoke SP to populate table with Expense info
                    List<ExpenseDistModel> newExpenseModelList = DataAccess.getExpenseList();

                    //invoke SP to populate Category Dropdown in Create New Expense
                    List<CategoryModel> newCategoryList = DataAccess.getCategory();

                    //invoke SP to populate SubCategory Dropdown in Create New Expense
                    // List<SubCategoryModel> newExpenseSubCategoryList = DataAccess.getSubCategory();

                    List<SubCategoryModel> newExpenseSubCategoryList = new List<SubCategoryModel>();

                    //instantiate the newExpenseViewModel along with the values previously fetched by expenseDistModel
                    newExpenseViewModel = new NewExpenseViewModel(newExpenseModelList, newCategoryList, newExpenseSubCategoryList);

                    //return the viewModel
                    return View("CreateNewExpense", newExpenseViewModel);
                }
            }
                return RedirectToAction("EditExpense", new
                {
                    newExpenseCategory = newExpenseViewModel.selectedExpenseCategory,

                    newExpenseSubCategory = newExpenseViewModel.selectedExpenseSubCategory,

                    expenseCreditFund = newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseCreditFund,

                    expenseCreditORGN = newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseCreditORGN,

                    expenseCreditProgram = newExpenseViewModel.newExpenseCreditProgram,

                    submitAction = submitAction,

                    modifiedby = "test"
                });
        }
```

when I hover over newExpenseViewModel I see all the values but the radiobutton, that's null - any ideas?

UPDATE: I fixed my issue by passing the viewmodel instead of the list itself to the radiobutton - now I need to initialize it to "Unchecked"

```
 <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CopyRadioButton,@i, new{@checked = false})</td>
```

Comment: Please note that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag is intended for questions about the *pattern*, whereas your question targets the ASP.NET-specific implementation. Use [tag:asp.net-mvc] and/or one of the version-specific tags, instead.

Comment: acknowledged - thank you.

Comment: Please format your code and make them readable. Also, if anything commented out (like those in your view) that's not related to your question, you can delete them.

Comment: Are you going to post the javascript that is calling your controller method? Where is the CopyRadioButton property being populated? What does the NewExpenseViewModel view model look like?

Comment: At the end I ended up passing the view model to my RadioButtonFor instead of the list itself and that works - now I'm just struggling with defaulting the RadioButton to "Unchecked" not sure how to accomplish that:

Comment: You use of a single radio button makes so sense at all. Radio buttons are used to select on option from a group of many (you need at least 2). Best guess is that you need a checkbox but you have not shown you model so impossible to help you. In any case using `new { @Name="group1", @Value="copy"}` would never have bound to anything . **Never** attempt to override the `name` and `value` attributes!

Comment: But nothing else you are doing here makes sense anyway. All you have a a lot of readonly textboxes which obviously cant be edited so they should not be posted back (unless of course you really do want to slow down your app). Then there is the awful use of inline styles (use css) and the `onfocus()`. And finally your `return RedirectToAction()` will always fail so impossible to understand what your really trying to do.

Comment: And finally `new{ @checked = false }` sets the `checked` attribute (as does `checked="checked"` or `checked="true"` or `checked="anyOtherValueYouCanThinkOf"`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it makes sense because it is a list of items and it's working perfectly now.

Comment: I can't post the rest of the code as I am not at work right now but my view is working the way I needed it to and so is my model and controller -  you can insult me all you want is all the same to me, at the end the ignorant here saying this doesn't make sense is not me.